# Adding multiple new key-value pairs to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I am trying to add key-value pairs to a nested dictionary. I tried a few approaches but I am not able to do it properly. This is the code that I have written:

```py
dict1 = {}
dict1['name'] = {'domain': "something"}
i=0
while i < 10:
    new = 'route'+str(i)
    dict1['name']['routes'] = {new: {'bit_value': i}}
    i = i+1
print(dict1)
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
{'name': {'domain': 'something', 'routes': {'route9': {'bit_value': 9}}}}
```

This is the kind of output that I want:

```
{'name': {'domain': 'something', 'routes': {'route1': {'bit_value': 1}, 'route2': {'bit_value': 2}, 'route3': {'bit_value': 3}, 'route4': {'bit_value': 4} ...}}}
```

I tried using this version as well, but it throws a Keyerror:

```
import collections

dict1 = collections.defaultdict(dict)
dict1['name'] = {'domain': "something"}
i = 0
while i < 10:
    new = 'route'+str(i)
    dict1['name']['routes'][new] =  {'bit_value': i}
    i = i+1
print(dict1)
```

Error message:

```
dict1['name']['routes'][new] =  {'bit_value': i}
KeyError: 'routes'
```

It would be nice if this problem can be solved without changing into a for loop as the while loop will make it easier for me to integrate this with rest of the code that I have written. I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the `routes` sub-dictionary, then insert items.

```
import collections

dict1 = collections.defaultdict(dict)
dict1['name'] = {'domain': "something"}
i = 0
##########
dict1['name']['routes'] = {} 
##########
while i < 10:
    new = 'route'+str(i)
    dict1['name']['routes'][new] =  {'bit_value': i}
    i = i+1

print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original solution, `dict1['name']['routes']` is replaced with a new dictionary with only 1 key every time.

In your alternative version, `dict1` is a `defaultdict`. So you can access e.g. `dict1['randomkey']` without initializing it, but `dict1['name']` or `dict1['name']['routes']` is not a `defaultdict`. `defaultdict(dict)` means the values are normal dictionaries. If you need the values to be `defaultdict` as well, you can do `defaultdict(defaultdict(dict))`

But that's not what you want. You don't actually need to deal with default key values. You only need to initialize `dict1['name']['routes']` once to a normal dictionary:

```py
dict1 = {'name': {'domain': 'something', 'routes': {}}}
for i in range(10):
    dict1['name']['routes'][f'route{i}'] = {'bit_value': i}
```

A few bonus tips

1. Don't mix `'string'` with `"string"`
2. Use `for i in range(10)` instead of a while loop. Much simpler and easier to read
3. Use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to format string `f'route{i}'`

As a matter of fact, your code can also be achieved with dictionary comprehension

```py
dict1 = {'name': {'domain': 'something'}}
dict1['name']['routes'] = {f'route{i}': {'bit_value': i} for i in range(10)}
```